# How do I inject <br> into text entered through a textarea in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, gsub

I have a textarea form which takes a large block of text.  In this text area, I do a carriage return to end the paragraph and another carriage return to separate the paragraphs.

That text is in @contact_postalcard.message.

However, I need to output into an HTML file.  The HTML file has been loaded as a long string which contains 'ReplaceThisWithPostalcardMessage' in it.  I want to gsub the text from @contact_postalcard.message for ReplaceThisWithPostalcardMessage.

The problem is that the HTML file does not have any 
 tags for each carriage return.  As a result, I get one long run-on paragraph.

How can I format the substituted value in the HTML file properly?

```
addr_template = addr_template.gsub(/ReplaceThisWithPostalcardMessage/, @contact_postalcard.message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
addr_template = addr_template.gsub(/ReplaceThisWithPostalcardMessage/,
  @contact_postalcard.message.gsub("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: Okay, sounds like this is the winner!  Let me try it and go!

Comment: This requires making the whole @contact_postalcard string html_safe, which allows for easy html injection.
You should use the #simple_format approach, which takes care of sanitizing the html.

Answer (score 4):

Use the textarea as normal then display using :

```
simple_format(data_from_textarea)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, that helps when displaying into rails view...this is injecting into a static .html file?  It is getting gsubed into a string being io.read into a string....would this work?  if so, how?  thanks!

Comment: addr_template = simple_format(addr_template.gsub(/ReplaceThisWithPostalcardMessage/, @contact_postalcard.message))